# Variables and storing/comparing values in a dust.js template

Tags: javascript, json, dust.js

Is it possible using dust.js templates to compare a view value from one iteration in a loop to the next? This seems a question of context and I don't see this explained in the dust.js docs, or in any posts here. So for example, with this JSON view:

```
{
    people: [ 
        { name: "Fred", row: 1 },
        { name: "Harry", row: 2 },
        { name: "Linda", row: 2 },
        { name: "Mary", row: 5 },
        { name: "Bob", row: 6 },
        { name: "Joey", row: 6 }
    ]
}
```

if I wanted this HTML output:

```
<br/>Fred
<br/>Harry Linda
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>Mary
<br/>Bob Joey
```

how would the template differ from this simple one?

```
{#people}
    <br/>{name}
{/people}
```

I realize dust.js is meant to be logicless and that I could structure the data differently like this below, but I'd like to know if what I'm describing can be done.

```
{
    people: [ 
        line: [ { name: "Fred", row: 1 } ],
        line: [ { name: "Harry", row: 2 }, { name: "Linda", row: 2 } ],
        line: [ ],
        line: [ ],
        line: [ { name: "Mary", row: 5 } ],
        line: [ { name: "Bob", row: 6 }, { name: "Joey", row: 6 } ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm nearly certain this can't be done.  As you've said, use the second approach, although in that approach, you no longer need the row attribute.

Comment: So no way to keep a running total then either on numeric values? Even though some would say this should be in the biz logic.

Comment: Nope Jim, there's just no way to store a value in a variable so you can look at it later.  You can use $idx to see what position you are in in the people loop, but that doesn't give you enough information to do what you want.